# The vertical alignment is not working for several merged text fields (isPrintRepeatedValues=false)

Tags: jasper-reports

In the 4th column ("*Estimated Amt to be...*") I am not able to bring the value to center eventhough its the cells of two rows are merged.

[image: Click to see the image]

Things I did to make it look like merged is:

1. removed the bottom border of the cell in *Detail* band.
2. added the top border of the columnfooter band
3. checked the option not to print repeated values ( *isPrintRepeatedValues="false"*).
4. the data is passed as *JRbeanCOllectionDatasource* (which basically is a list) to the fields of *Detail* band.

Could you please guide me.

---

***UPDATED***:

Use the help of @Alexk to resolve this by using subreport for the dynamic fields and the merged field is set to  *isPrintRepeatedValues="false"  & StrectType = RelativeToBandHeight

Now I am getting a empty line between the detailBand and the columnFooter. Any idea whats inducing this empty line ? find the diagram.

[image: empty line between detail and column footer after merging]

Comment: @AlexK thanks. I used the solution that you pointed me and I created a subreport and I was able merge and bring the cells to center but I am getting a extra empt line now between detail and columnfooter band. Any idea what could bve inducing this empty line ?